# Python mocking- understand the concept and necessity

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, mocking

**First of all I really want to understand WHY should I use mocking (Python Mock library).**

What's the difference between quickly making a small object for the need of testing something and using a mock object?

What are the advantages of mocking over other methods (I would really need some "live" examples to understand this one)?  Is mocking essential in some cases?

Also: what's the difference between a mock object and magicmock object? How to they connect?

**The second thing is WHAT/WHERE to mock.**

Should I only mock, for example, the database query results?
I mean: does the mocked data should always be a remote one?

**tl;dr:** Please explain the mocking concept in Python to someone who never used it in any language.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414032/why-create-mock-objects?rq=1

Comment: But there's nothing about Python there, although it has a small part of the answers.
Furthermore there aren't too many examples there.

My situation is: I've never used mocking, now I have to mock things using Python. I need something like "Mocking in Python for dummies" ;)

Comment: @user2091046 +1 because I have these questions. But really, this is like five questions in one, probably should have been split up. E.g., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370617/hard-coded-mock-objects-vs-mocking-framework

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A mock object is meant to quickly and easily represent some complex object without having to manually go through and set up stubs for that object during a test.  It's simply a useful utility for making writing tests a bit easier.

As to what/where to mock, anything that is external to the module-under-test should be mocked.  All you want to test is the current module code, not the code for some module that is being called by the module-under-test.

A quick example is some code that uses the `simplejson` module.

```
import simplejson

def my_fn(args):
  return simplejson.dumps({'args': args})
```

All you want to test is that the function `my_fn` makes the correct call to `simplejson.dumps()`, so you mock `simplejson`. You don't really care if the object passed to `simplejson` is converted to json correctly as testing that is in the scope of the `simplejson` module (which has it's own set of tests that you can run if you're so inclined).

```
import working_code
import mock

@mock.patch('working_code.simplejson')
def test_my_fn(mock_simplejson):
    working_code.my_fn('test-args')
    mock_simplejson.dumps.assert_called_with({'args': 'test-args'})
```

Note that `mock.patch` is simply a nice way to inject and remove mocks for a particular test.  After `test_my_fn` is run, `working_code.simplejson` returned to the state before the function was called.  If that's confusing, you can think of the test example as:

```
import working_code
import mock

def test_my_fn():
    mock_simplejson = mock.Mock()
    working_code.simplejson = mock_simplejson
    working_code.my_fn('test-args')
    mock_simplejson.dumps.assert_called_with({'args': 'test-args'})
```