# Programming offline in Python when using serial commands?

Tags: python, serial-port

I'm using Python to interface with some devices, mainly through serial ports. However, when I'm not at work and want to make modifications, I can't test the code because the devices aren't connected to my home computer.

I'm wondering if there's a way to send dummy values through the serial port commands without causing error messages that stop the application. I've considered using if statements, but they can make the code difficult to read later on.

Any suggestion ?

Thanks !

Comment: Create a [Mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python mocking- understand the concept and necessity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19918700/python-mocking-understand-the-concept-and-necessity) and [Using python's mock patch.object to change the return value of a method called within another method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18191275/using-pythons-mock-patch-object-to-change-the-return-value-of-a-method-called-w)

Comment: Isn't it possible to use programs like these? [ezramorris/PyVirtualSerialPorts](https://github.com/ezramorris/PyVirtualSerialPorts), [Null-modem emulator](https://sourceforge.net/projects/com0com/) Although you will also need to write a device-side simulator yourself.